# Password Meter Validation - RegEx

Tags: regex, validation, passwords, meter

A password meter guides the user with developing a strong password. I would like to have the password requirements below implemented on the meter. I've added the highlighted code below with RegEx, however the code does not detect the required password guidelines. What is the correct code to detect the requirements below?

- 8+ characters
- Upper and lowercase letters
- Special characters
- Must not contain 4+ continuous letters
- Must not contain 4+ continuous numbers

**Example:** 
Test%401 =   Insufficient
2323Ejsdh! = Insufficient
Tlv!897% =   Strong 
302^PLs# =   Strong

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
if(val.length > 7 && val.match(/\d{4}/) && val.match(/[a-zA-Z]{4}/) && val.match(/[~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),+,-,?]/))
```

Comment: Did you intend to match commas with `/[~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),+,-,?]/`? If yes, one is enough. and hyphen must be at the end of the class.

Comment: No. Sorry. Commas are there to separate the special characters.

Comment: *3+ continuous letters* - none of the examples fit this. All have 3 continuous letters.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the post.

Comment: Since you posted [another similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852339/password-validation-with-sequential-letters-and-numbers-regex), do you still need help with this one?

Comment: Yes I do need help. I have not received an answer yet to my question. Thanks for following up @stribizhev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single-regex approach for your task:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^\w\s])(?!.*(?:[a-zA-Z]{4}|\d{4})).{8,}$
```

If you need to match specific "special" characters, use your `[~!@#$%^&*()+?-]` class instead of `[^\w\s]` (*not a word or whitespace character*).
Breaking down:

```
var rx = RegExp ("^" +                            // Start of string
                "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +               // Letter is required
                "(?=.*[^\\w\\s])" +              // A special character is required
                "(?!.*(?:[a-zA-Z]{4}|\\d{4}))" + // No 4 letters or digits on end are allowed
                ".{8,}" +                        // The whole length can be 8 or more characters
                "$"                              // End of string
              );
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var ins = "Test%401";
var ins1 = "2323Ejsdh!";

var strong1 = "Tlv!897%";
var strong2 = "302^PLs#";

var rx = RegExp ("^" +                            // Start of string
                 "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +               // Letter is required
                 "(?=.*[^\\w\\s])" +              // A special character is required
                 "(?!.*(?:[a-zA-Z]{4}|\\d{4}))" + // No 4 letters or digits on end are allowed
                 ".{8,}" +                        // The whole length can be 8 or more characters
                 "$"                              // End of string
                );
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += rx.test(ins) + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += rx.test(ins1) + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += rx.test(strong1) + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += rx.test(strong2) + "<br/>";
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

**Another way is to split the conditions:**

```js
function CheckPass(val) {
   if(val.length <= 7) {
       return "Password is too short!";
   }
   else if (/\d{4}/.test(val)) {
          return "Password contains 4 digits on end!";
   }
   else if (/[a-zA-Z]{4}/.test(val)) {
          return "Password contains 4 letters on end!";
   }
   else if (!/[~!@#$%^&*()+?-]/.test(val)) {
          return "Password must contain at least one special character from the \"~!@#$%^&*()+?-\" set!";
   }
   else if (!/[a-z]/i.test(val)) {
          return "Password must contain at least one letter!";
   }
       else
           return "Password is strong!";
}
    
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML +=  "<b>Test%401</b>: "+CheckPass("Test%401") + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML +=  "<b>2323Ejsdh!</b>: "+CheckPass("2323Ejsdh!") + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML +=  "<b>23!34%12!</b>: "+CheckPass("23!34%12!") + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML +=  "<b>23w34W12D</b>: "+CheckPass("23w34W12D") + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += "<b>Tlv</b>: "+ CheckPass("Tlv") + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML +=  "<b>Tlv!897%</b>: "+CheckPass("Tlv!897%") + "<br/>";
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML +=  "<b>302^PLs#</b>: "+ CheckPass("302^PLs#");
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev Can it catch the 4 letters or digits at the start and during the length of the password as well? You mentioned "on end are allowed"

Comment: No, using capture groups inside a negative look-ahead makes no sense since there will be no match. You need to split the regex as it is done in your question. I will re-answer with a split version as soon as I can.

Comment: I added a snippet with a function returning the messages based on whether the password is strong or misses something important.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you @stribizhez