# Regular expression for sequential numbers like 12345 or 456789

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to prevent entering `5` digit sequential numbers like `12345`, `45678` etc. in a text box.

I had tried with the following regular expression, but it is not working

```
var regex = /^\(?[0-9]{3}(\-|\)) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852339/password-validation-with-sequential-letters-and-numbers-regex

Comment: /12345|23456|34567|45678|56789/ and add more as much as you want

Comment: If you use HTML5 pattern attribute, use [`(?!(?:01234|12345|23456|34567|45678|56789|67890|78901|89012|90123)$).*`](https://regex101.com/r/vJ3rF6/1). Adjust as needed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew's answer allows 123456 (and generally longer strings containing 5-digit sequences), but maybe that's OK

Comment: @ChrisLear: Yeah, no idea. OP says "5 digit" sequences, maybe 6 digit ones are allowed. If not, [`^(?!.*(?:01234|12345|23456|34567|45678|56789|67890|78901|89012|90123)).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/vJ3rF6/2) can be used (with the `^` and `$` unnecessary in HTML5 pattern).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is better to use non regular expression based approach for this type of tasks. You can do this easily using `indexOf`. Regular expressions for these patterns become really complicated and un-readable.

```
var pattern = '0123456789012345789' //to match circular sequence as well.
if (pattern.indexOf(input) == -1) 
  console.log('good input')
else
  console.log('bad input')
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is used [`Tilde (~)`](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-tilde/) operator in search functions. Using `~` on `-1` converts it to `0`. The number 0 is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, meaning that it will evaluate to false when converted to a Boolean. Anything that is not falsy is truthy.

```js
const input = '12345';
const pattern = '0123456789012345789';
if (~pattern.indexOf(input))
  console.log('pattern in input');
else
  console.log('pattern not in input');
```

or you can use the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method:

```js
const input = '12345';
const pattern = '0123456789012345789';
if (pattern.includes(input))
  console.log('pattern in input');
else
  console.log('pattern not in input');
```