# Check if String has sequential or repeated characters in javascript (underscore)

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

I have code that I am trying to refactor. I'm new to javascript so I'm trying to make more readable code using functions in libraries like underscore.
The function below can detect when string contains 3 or more ordered characters such as (234, efg, LmN) and when string contains 3 or more repeated (lll, 444, MMm, @@@)

```js
const input = "Dfdf123125";

    const myStr = input.toLowerCase();
    const n = 3;

    let isRepeating = false;
    let isSequential = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < myStr.length; i++) {
      if (i + (n - 1) <= myStr.length) {
        let isRepeatingTemp = false;

        let isSequentialTemp = false;
        for (let j = i; j < i + n; j++) {
           (myStr.charCodeAt(i) === myStr.charCodeAt(j)) ? isRepeatingTemp = true: isRepeatingTemp = false;
           (myStr.charCodeAt(i) === myStr.charCodeAt(j) - (n - 1)) ? isSequentialTemp = true : isSequentialTemp = false;
        }

        if (isRepeatingTemp) isRepeating = true;

        if (isSequentialTemp) isSequential = true;

      }
    }
```

I'm trying to to see if I can optimize this and make it more readable with underscore and/or even make time/space complexity better. I know this can also be done with regex but I'm trying to get it done without it.

Comment: To improve the time complexity, you can keep track of the last two characters in the sequence, instead of doing the inner `for` loop.

Comment: Can you elborate Sumner Evans?

Comment: @jesjolly Have a look into [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), you can use this to get a chunk of the string. I believe this is what Summer Evans is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the inner `for` loop, I chunked the string to `n` using [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to see ahead `n` characters. I used [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find if it's sequential based off the `abc` and `num` constants([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37811296/10887412)). To see if it's repeating, I used [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) that loops through the chunk and check if they're similar and return a boolean based on the expression.

The result gives the output of each instance found, and if it was sequential or repeating.

```js
const input = "Dfdf123125";

function RepSeq(str, n) {
  var rep = false;
  var seq = false;
  var result = [];
  
  const num = '0123456789';
  const abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz';
  
  if (str.length < n) return false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i + n > str.length) break;

    var chunk = str.slice(i, i + n);
    var seqABC = abc.indexOf(chunk) > -1;
    var seq123 = num.indexOf(chunk) > -1;
    
    if (seq123 || seqABC) {
      seq = true;
      result.push(chunk);
    }
    
    if ([...chunk].every(v => v.toLowerCase() === chunk[0].toLowerCase())) {
      rep = true;
      result.push(chunk);
    }
  }
  
  return {
    repetition: rep,
    sequential: seq,
    out: result
  };
}


console.log(RepSeq(input, 3));

// Output:
// {
//   out: ["123"],
//   repetition: false,
//   sequential: true
// }
```

With this method, we're peeking at the string one block(`i`+`n`) at a time. Ex(`n=3`):

```
 1. [Dfd]f123125
 2. D[fdf]123125
 3. Df[df1]23125
 4. Dfd[f12]3125
 5. Dfdf[123]125 - Sequential!
 6. Dfdf1[231]25
 7. Dfdf12[312]5
 8. Dfdf123[125]
```