# string validation for 3 or more consecutive sequential alphanumeric characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, sequential, alphanumeric

I have a requirement for a password validator that the password may not include three alphabetically sequential characters or sequential numbers.

So passwords that include the following are considered invalid values

```
  abc   

  Abc

  123
```

Tried to see if I could get it with regex in javascript but I haven't been able to. Has anyone done that and if not regex, any javascript code that would check for sequential characters?

Thank you,

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to need to loop over all characters.toLower() starting at Index=2 and perform a charAt(Index) to check sequence.

Comment: You *could* do `/123|234|345|…|abc|bcd|…/i`, but really this is not a job for regex.

Comment: I haven given another similar but optimized answer there which you can check at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852339/password-validation-with-sequential-letters-and-numbers-regex/45991433#45991433